# Accessing JSON through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am a newbie with json and right now fighting with it. :) I am getting response with ajax call and I want to get all id values from json response. I am not sure what am I doing wrong, I already tried most of the solutions but none gave me a positive answer.

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Actions.php?action=update',
    type: 'post',
    data: '&id='+$id,
}).success(function(data) {
    var jsondata = JSON.parse(data);

    $.each(jsondata, function(i, item) {
       console.log(item.Records.id);
    });           
});
```

And error I am getting is this one:

> TypeError: item.Records is undefined

And this is my JSON response:

```
{"Result":"OK","Records":
[{"0":"111","id":"111","1":"20","free":"20"},
{"0":"127","id":"127","1":"20","free":"20"},
{"0":"133","id":"133","1":"20","free":"20"},
{"0":"134","id":"134","1":"20","free":"20"},
{"0":"135","id":"135","1":"20","free":"20"},
{"0":"326","id":"326","1":"20","free":"20"}]}
```

How can I acces all id and free values? Or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over `jsondata.Records`:

```
$.each(jsondata.Records, function (i, item) {
    console.log(item.id);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SLsTm/)

Comment: thank you a lot, it worked :) i am a newbie so i was trying to find a solution and everything i tried didnt work, so you helped me a lot, i will accept your answer when the time passes by :)

Comment: @enigmaticus no problem, gad to help.

Answer (score 3):

`jsondata.Records` is the array which contains further json objects,

Try,

```
$.each(jsondata.Records, function(i, item) {
   console.log(item.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
url: 'Actions.php?action=update',
type: 'post',
data: '&id='+$id,
dataType:'json'
 }).success(function(data) {

$.each(data.Record, function(i, item) {
   console.log(item.id);
});
```

});

pls use dataTye in your ajax setting.